# If $H < G$ and $g \in G$ how to prove that $A=\{ghg^{-1}, h \in H\}$ is a subgroup from $G$?

Tags: group-theory

The notation $<$ means subgroup, I was thinking about proving that $ab \in A$ and $b^{-1}\in A$ for $a,b \in A$ this bellow as I've tried so far:

Note that $ab \in A$ is equivalent to the solution (regarding $h$) for the equation below belonging to $H$:

$ab=ghg^{-1}$

so:

$h=g^{-1}abg$

$h=(g^{-1}a)(bg)$

since $H<G$ I have to proof, as it's closed under the omitted operator (.), that $g^{-1}a \in H$ and $bg \in H$, Is there any idea to going on?

Comment: Because $a\in A$, there exists $h_1\in H$ such that $a=gh_1g^{-1}$. Because $b\in A$, there exists $h_2\in H$ such that $b=gh_2g^{-1}$. Now multiply out $ab$ and see if there exists $h_3\in H$ such that $ab=gh_3g^{-1}$, to guarantee that $ab$ lies in $A$; likewise, compute $b^{-1}$ and see if there exists an $h_4\in H$ such that $b^{-1}= gh_4g^{-1}$

Comment: Conjugation is an automorphism. [The homomorphic image of a subgroup is a subgroup.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3176775/104041)